# Want to use the value returned by Select-Object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I have to add a route table and for this I need Index interface Id. I am using below script to find the index interface and add the route table. But, I am getting below error because Route table need Integer value "80", but this script is giving the input "@{ifIndex=80}".
Please advise how to fix this ?

**Script:**
PS C:\Users\Administrator> route -p add 40.127.64.19/32 0.0.0.0 IF (Get-NetIPInterface | where-object {$_.interfaceAlias -like "Test VPN*"} | select-object ifindex)

**Error:**
C:\windows\system32\ROUTE.EXE: bad interface index @{ifIndex=80}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach rather:

```
Get-NetIPInterface -AddressFamily IPv4 |
  Where-Object {$_.interfaceAlias -like "Test VPN*"} |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty ifIndex |
      ForEach-Object {
        route.exe -p add 40.127.64.19/32 0.0.0.0 IF $_
      }
```

### Explanation

Use **`Get-NetIPInterface -AddressFamily IPv4`**: without the `IPv4` parameter you could get both as follows:

```
Get-NetIPInterface -AddressFamily IPv4 |
  Where-Object {$_.interfaceAlias -like "Test VPN*"} |
    Select-Object ifIndex, InterfaceAlias, AddressFamily
```

> ```
> ifIndex InterfaceAlias AddressFamily
> ------- -------------- -------------
>      10 Test VPN                IPv6
>      10 Test VPN                IPv4
> ```

Use **`Select-Object -ExpandProperty ifIndex`**: *Specifies a property to select, and indicates that an attempt should be made to [**expand that property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-5.0#parameters).*

Use **`ForEach-Object`**: there are three possible cases as result of the `Where-Object` pipeline:

- exactly one object (desired), or
- no object (or `$null`), or
- more objects (an array) due to a wildcard in `-like "Test VPN*"`

The last two listed would cause `route.exe` syntax error in your approach (even if uses `-ExpandProperty`).

---

BTW, **always** use `.exe` extension in PowerShell. For instance, compare `where notepad` and `where.exe notepad` (or `Get-Command where` with `Get-Command where.exe`).